# Updating v-model data in form inputs with a series of methods in a Vuetify project?

Tags: vue.js, arguments, vuetify.js

I am attempting to update a series of `v-text-fields` (`type='number'`) so that after the user has entered in a numeric value, the number shown in the input will be updated with commas (so a value of 5032 would become 5,032 for example). I found [this article](https://medium.com/@khanusama20/how-to-apply-thousand-separator-in-input-type-number-using-vuejs-fd23fea631aa) and was able to accomplish what I'm after with a single input using the example provided...

Markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="visible === true">
    Enter Amount: <br>
    <input type="number" 
    v-model="amount" 
    placeholder="Enter Amount" 
    @blur="onBlurNumber"/>
</div>

<div v-if="visible === false">
  Enter Amount: <br>
  <input type="text" 
  v-model="amount" 
  placeholder="Enter Amount" 
  @focus="onFocusText"/>
</div>
```

Script:

```
data: {
    amount: null,
    temp: null,
    visible: true
},
methods: {
  onBlurNumber() {
        this.visible = false;     
        this.temp = this.amount;
        this.amount = this.thousandSeprator(this.amount);
    },
    onFocusText() {
        this.visible = true;
        this.amount = this.temp;
   },

   thousandSeprator(amount) {
       if (amount !== '' || amount !== undefined || amount !== 0  || amount !== '0' || amount !== null) {
    return amount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       } else {
           return amount;
       }
   }
}
```

...but I want to make the methods generic enough to work with any numeric `v-text-fields` I am using. I have been able to update a parameter value within my methods, but have been unable to actually update the `v-model` data of the `v-text-field`.

Markup:

```
<div id="app">
 <div v-if="visible === true">
    <v-text-field 
      class="mb-3 d-inline-block"
      type="number" 
      prepend-inner-icon="attach_money" 
      v-model="amount" 
      label="Amount"
      mask="##########" 
      outline
      :rules="[v => !!v || 'Amount is required']" 
      @blur="onBlurNumber(amount)"
      required>
    </v-text-field>
  </div>

  <div v-if="visible === false">
    <v-text-field 
      class="mb-3 d-inline-block"
      prepend-inner-icon="attach_money" 
      v-model="amount" 
      label="Amount"
      outline
      @focus="onFocusText(amount)"
      >
     </v-text-field>
   </div>
```

Script:

```
onBlurNumber(data) {
    this.visible = false;     
    this.temp = data;
    data = this.thousandSeprator(data);
},
onFocusText(data) {
    this.visible = true;
    data = this.temp;
},
```

I can log the value of data in these methods and confirm that the commas are being applied correctly, but now I don't know how to send the data value back to update the `v-text-field`'s v-model. I experimented with selecting the `v-text-field` using a `ref` value but the `ref` turns up as an `undefined` value when the method is triggered.

Does anyone know how I can update the `v-model` of the `v-text-field` using arguments in this sort of fashion so the methods are reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have multiple `data` items for each of the text fields:

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    // Field 1
    temp1: null,
    amount1: null,
    visible1: true,

    // Field 2
    temp2: null,
    amount2: null,
    visible2: true
  }
}
```

In your markup, when calling the method you could then pass the name of the property, or maybe its suffix.

```html
<v-text-field @blur="onBlurNumber('2')"
```

And in your script, you could update the data items by using dynamic properties:

```js
methods: {
    onBlurNumber(suffix) {
      this["visible" + suffix] = false;
      this["temp" + suffix] = this["amount" + suffix];
      this["amount" + suffix] = this.thousandSeprator(this["amount" + suffix]);
    },
```

[Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/generictextfieldmask-jd63w) of two independent text inputs that are calling the same methods to achieve this. We could refactor this to reduce the number of data items using arrays if needed.